# What does this mean? Re: Inclusion in HTML or CSS using PHP

Tags: php, html, obfuscation

Inclusion in HTML or CSS using PHP
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Inclusion_in_HTML_or_CSS_using_PHP

I have to hide the source of my images, to avoid someone from copying down the entire folder.

I tried using IONCUBE before, but now I want simpler implementation.

Again, I want to know generated HTML page source obfuscation techniques not the obfuscation of PHP files.

EDIT:
I want this part of code in the generated HTML page to be obfuscated.

```
<div id="ImgHolder">
        <img src="./images/blank.gif" id="FullSizeImageTail"/>
        <img src="http://blah.blahblah.edu/random/<?=$_GET['random']?>/<?=$_GET['random2']?>" id="FullSizeImage"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a quick little PHP script that does the image loading. You can put this process script in a directory segregated from all the images and then link to it like this:

```
<img src="http://blah.blahblah.edu/path/to/scripts/image.php" id="c" />
```

And the **image.php** file would look something like this:

```
$file = '/path/to/yourimage.png';
$size = getimagesize($file);
$type = $size['mime'];
header('Content-type: '.$type);
print file_get_contents($file);
exit;
```

---

You could of course supply variables to the image.php and do logic in the image.php file to get specific files.

For example:

```
<img src="http://blah.blahblah.edu/path/to/scripts/image.php?n=<?=base64_encode('my_image.png')?>" id="c" />
```

PHP checking for `$_GET` variable:

```
if(isset($_GET['n'])) {
  $file = '/path/to/'.base64_decode($_GET['n']);
  if(file_exists($file)) {
    $size = getimagesize($file);
    $type = $size['mime'];
    header('Content-type: '.$type);
    print file_get_contents($file);
    exit;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I read in another comment your worried about registered users downloading your paintings. You can also prevent hotlinking (if that's something that interests you as well) by including this in the **image.php** file at the top.

```
//Don't allow hotlinking
$referer = explode("/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
if($referer[2] != "blah.blahblah.edu") {
  $my_img = imagecreate(265, 90);
  $background = imagecolorallocate($my_img, 0, 0, 255);
  $text_color = imagecolorallocate($my_img, 255, 255, 0);
  $line_color = imagecolorallocate($my_img, 128, 255, 0);
  imagestring($my_img, 4, 30, 25, "Hot Linking Not Permitted", $text_color);
  imagestring($my_img, 4, 30, 50, "blah.blahblah.edu", $text_color);
  imagesetthickness($my_img, 5);
  imageline($my_img, 30, 45, 230, 45, $line_color);
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  imagejpeg($my_img);
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Obfuscating HTML code is completely pointless. There's no such thing as clever HTML code, and no one cares what your HTML code is.

The meaning of the code that you want to obfuscate in your question will still be very obvious after obfuscation anyway.

Consider the code that you want to obfuscate:

```
<div id="ImgHolder">
    <img src="./images/blank.gif" id="FullSizeImageTail"/>
    <img src="http://blah.blahblah.edu/random/<?=$_GET['random']?>/<?=$_GET['random2']?>" id="FullSizeImage"/>
</div>
```

Well, all of the HTML symbols have to remain. That means you cant change "div", "img", "src", "id", etc.

All you can change are "ImgHolder", "FullSizeImageTail" and "FullSizeImage".
The addresses of images and so on must remain.

So your code visible to users of your website might become:

```
<div id="a"><img src="./images/blank.gif" id="b"/><img src="http://blah.blahblah.edu/random/123/456" id="c"/></div>
```

Did that really hide anything?

Comment: I need to hide the URL from displaying http://blah.blahblah.edu/random/123/456 Because I have many important and rare images in that folder which I don't want the user to download enmasse.

Comment: provide protection for the folder then, ensuring that the content can only be accessed using a PHP (or similar) script as Michael Irigoyen has suggested... then you can even store the files outside of the htdocs folder hierarchy

Answer (score 2):

You can't have the actual page markup be base64-encoded. The Wikipedia article you linked is about data URIs — that is, you can include them on a page where a URI is expected. This *does* include an `<a>` tag, but that will only allow you to include the linked page inline in the same file. In browsers that support using a data URI that way, once you've navigated to the page in the data link, the source code will show in plaintext. It doesn't obfuscate the source any more than a normal link does. Ditto for iframes.

And even if you could do this, the warnings about how useless obfuscation is still apply. Base64-encoding in particular is really bad obfuscation, because it's intentionally reversible just by typing "decode base64" into Google.

If you want to gain some level of protection against somebody downloading all your images without requiring authorization and authentication, your best bet would be to use an algorithm that generates complex and unpredictable names for the image files and turn off the directory index page. Then they could only download the images you explicitly send to them without a lot of brute-forcing.

Comment: So, I can rule out base64 encoding. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

The pointlessness part comes from the idea that you have them wide open on the web anyway, so they are there. But it really seems like you just want clients to not get them all at once. This might be achived by 1) deny directory listing and; 2) using a different naming scheme for your images which reduces automated guessing.

This approach differs from Michael's answer in that this is less exploitable. anything with a simple numeric naming convention implies a sequential naming convention and sequential names are easy to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the directory so that it does not list the contents of it.

"If you create a new directory (or folder) on your website, and do not put a "index.html" file in it, you may be surprised to find that your visitors can get a directory listing of all the files in that folder. For example, if you create a folder called "incoming", you can see everything in that directory simply by typing "http://www.example.com/incoming/" in your browser. No password or anything is needed." - http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml

Comment: my site is already password protected. I want to make sure that the registered members do not download the paintings.